# Ember: Updating parent component property causes full reload

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components

I'm trying to update properties of a Parent-Component from a Child-Component, once links in this Child-Component are clicked. But this is causing unexpected full-page reload.

I'm composing components. From the Parent-Component I make available properties and a (clousure action) to the Child-Component.

Everything seems to be working correctly when I hard-code the "key" property of the Parent-Component. But when I modify it from the Child-Component it makes a full-reload, resetting properties to their default values, and therefore, not filtering.

All properties are chained one another, as a cascade.

This is my code:

Parent-Component.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import moment from 'moment';

const { Component, computed, inject } = Ember;

export default Component.extend({

  calculateDates: inject.service(),

  key: 'week',
  dateOne: computed('key', function(){
    return this.get('calculateDates').getFirstDayOf(this.get('key'));
  }),
  dateTwo: computed('key', function(){
    return this.get('calculateDates').getLastDayOf(this.get('key'));
  }),
  filteredModel: computed('dateOne', 'dateTwo', function() {
    const modelToFilter = this.get('model');
    return modelToFilter.filter((item) => {
      const itemDate = item.get("date");
      return itemDate >= dateOne && itemDate <= dateTwo;
    });
  }),
  arrayForChildComponent: computed('dateOne', 'dateTwo', function() {
    const formatedDates = [
      moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      moment(this.get('dateOne')).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      moment(this.get('dateTwo')).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
   ];
    const routeTitle = ['Today', 'Week', 'Month'];
    const routes = [];
    for (var i=0; i < formatedDates.length; i++) {
      let queryParams = formatedDates[i];
      if (routeTitle[i]=='Week') queryParams = `${formatedDates[i]}-to-${formatedDates[i + 1]}`;
      if (routeTitle[i]=='Month') queryParams = moment(new Date()).format('MMMM');
      routes.push(
        { route : 'authenticated.meetings.list',
          name : routeTitle[i],
          queryParams : queryParams });
    }
    return routes;
  }),
  actions: {
    setFilterKey(value) {
      this.set('key', value.toLowerCase());
    }
  }
});
```

Parent-Component template

```
{{yield (hash
    header=(
      component 'header-component'
    )
    groups=(
      component 'meetings-component'
      meetings=filteredModel
    )
    nav=(
      component 'Child-Component'
      arrayForChildComponent=arrayForChildComponent
      onListItemClick=(action 'setFilterKey')
    )
)}}
```

Route-View template

```
{{#Parent-Component model=model as |filter| }}
  {{#filter.header}}
    {{filter.nav}}
  {{/filter.header}}
  {{filter.groups}}
{{/Parent-Component}}
```

Child-Component template (filter.nav)

```
{{#each arrayForChildComponent as |route|}}
    <li class={{liClass}} onClick={{action onListItemClick route.name}}>
      {{#link-to route.route (query-params date=route.queryParams) class=aClass}}
        {{route.name}}
      {{/link-to}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish, is set the key to the name it has the  tag.

- I've also tried with (action (mut key) route.name), importing the key from the Parent-Component.
- Also tried importing the action from the Parent-Component and use it inside Child-Component.
- And finally, it wasn't liveReload. I disabled it.

Everything has the same effect, they change the key from Parent-Component, update the filters, and reload the page.

Very frustrating.

Any ideas?

#### Update

I took out the event handler onClick, relying on event propagation of the nested link. Now it works, properties are properly updated, but the queryParameters set by the nested link won't reflect in the URL until the second click. Neither the 'active' class will appear until the second click.

```
{{#each arrayForChildComponent as |route|}}
    <li class={{liClass}} {{action onListItemClick route.name}}>
      {{#link-to route.route (query-params date=route.queryParams) class=aClass}}
        {{route.name}}
      {{/link-to}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: The `link-to` is capturing the click and routing you to another page, before the click is received by the action.